# Strongloop passport component returns "active" from loopback.getCurrentContext() empty

Tags: node.js, passport.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have this `var context = loopback.getCurrentContext();` that returns me under context.active.acccessToken the current Token used in the call (tested in the Explorer).

Now, when trying to use the Passport component, I copied the code form the server.js [example git](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) and put it on my boot/aaa-scripts.js  the context.active varible is an empty {}.

```
    // Passport configurators..
    var loopbackPassport = require('loopback-component-passport');
    var PassportConfigurator = loopbackPassport.PassportConfigurator;
    var passportConfigurator = new PassportConfigurator(app);

    // attempt to build the providers/passport config
    var config = {};
    try {
      config = require('../../providers.json');
    } catch (err) {
      console.trace(err);
      process.exit(1); // fatal
    }

    // The access token is only available after boot
    app.middleware('auth', loopback.token({
      model: app.models.AccessToken
    }));

    app.middleware('session:before', loopback.cookieParser(app.get('cookieSecret')));
    app.middleware('session', loopback.session({
      secret: 'kitty',
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: true
    }));
    passportConfigurator.init();

    passportConfigurator.setupModels({
      userModel: app.models.Member,
      userIdentityModel: app.models.UserIdentity,
      userCredentialModel: app.models.UserCredential
    });

    for (var s in config) {
      var c = config[s];
      c.session = c.session !== false;
      passportConfigurator.configureProvider(s, c);
    }


    var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;
    app.get('/auth/account', ensureLoggedIn('/'), function(req, res, next) {
      res.send(req.user);
    });
```

I have commented out parts of the copied code, and the part that's getting me trouble is:

```
    // The access token is only available after boot
    app.middleware('auth', loopback.token({
      model: app.models.AccessToken
    }));

    app.middleware('session:before', loopback.cookieParser(app.get('cookieSecret'));
    app.middleware('session', loopback.session({
      secret: 'kitty',
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: true
    }));
```

I have tried both AccessToken and accessToken

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to attach a User-related models to your datasource first:

```
app.models.AccessToken.attachTo(dataSource);
```

Comment: I have this in the model-config.js


      "AccessToken": {
        "dataSource": "db",
        "public": true
      }

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm Using an Angular app, I ended up commenting this 3 lines

```
app.middleware('auth', loopback.token({
  model: app.models.AccessToken
}));
```

Everything seens to be working all right.

Comment: i finally change it for: 

app.use(loopback.token());

source: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport/issues/41#issuecomment-120564592